# CSS white-space nowrap expand flexbox's child width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm learning CSS and I'm having a problem with text-overflow. I have a flex-box with two child. I want child 2 fit into its parent and the text-content will be cut if it too long. But when I add `white-space: nowrap` to text then child-2 width is expanded. What did I do wrong here ?

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.child-1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child-1">This is child 1</div>
<div class="child-2">
  <div class="text">A really long long long long text</div>
  <div class="text">Another really long long long long text</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what `white-space: nowrap` does - it stops the text from breaking at white space and wrapping to a new line.

Your `.parent` is set at a max-width: 200px so child-2 it cannot grow to to fit the longer text, and the single line is too long to fit into the space beside child-1, so it has to extend outside the parent - there is nowhere else for it to go.

I presume what you want to do is ***hide*** the part of the text that is extending out from the parent?

To do that you can use `overflow` to hide any content that extends outside of the child-2 div like this:

```
.child-2 { overflow:hidden; }
```

See more about the overflow property here: [Mozilla MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

**Example hiding the overflow:**

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.child-2{
  overflow:hidden;
}

.child-1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child-1">This is child 1</div>
<div class="child-2">
  <div class="text">A really long long long long text</div>
  <div class="text">Another really long long long long text</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I have one more question. I've already set the text div with overflow and text-overflow property. Why this text div does not hide the content inside ?

Comment: @Tino Nothing was limiting the width of the text so the overflow was never triggered. It's parent (`child-2`) had `overflow:visible` (this is the default when none is set), so it was bring displayed at it's full width (you can check the size in the browser's element inspector). That meant that it's children were also using the full width. When you set `overflow:hidden` on `text`s parent, that limits the width of the display so the text is also limited now.

Comment: @FluffyKitten spent a day finding this. Thanks a lot!